# jQuery body click when clicking outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a div I want to hide when clicking outside it.

It almost works, except the button class is only changing once every two times.

I click on the button, the active button class is added and the dropdown slides down, I click somewhere outside the dropdown, it slides up and the button class returns to it's original state. BUT, when I repeat this, the button class 'isActive' is not added.

Here's the function:

```
function toggleSelectGroupList(){
    $('#groupListSortby').slideToggle(30);


    $('body').click(function(){  
        $('#groupListSortby').click(function(e) {    e.stopPropagation();   })
        $('#groupListSortby').hide(); 
        $('.sortFriends .btngrey .gfx').toggleClass('isActive');
        $('.sortFriends .btngrey a').toggleClass('isActive');
    }); 
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="sortFriends">

<div class="btngrey">
    <span class="gfx"></span>
    <a onClick="toggleSelectGroupList()">All friends</a>
</div>

<div class="dropdownList" id="groupListSortby">
    <ul>
        <li class="isActive">
            <span class="gfx"></span>
            <a href="#">All friends</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Recently added</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <a href="#">The Railers</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind your `click` handlers from the beginning, and the propagation stop should be immediately bound as well, like this overall:

```
$(function() {
  $(".sortFriends .btngrey a").click(function(e) {
    $('#groupListSortby').slideToggle(30);
    $('.sortFriends .btngrey .gfx, .sortFriends .btngrey a').toggleClass('isActive');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#groupListSortby').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();   
  });
  $('body').click(function(){  
    $('#groupListSortby').hide(); 
    $('.sortFriends .btngrey .gfx, .sortFriends .btngrey a').removeClass('isActive');
  }); 
});
```

To match, your `<a>` shouldn't have an `onclick` inline with this anymore, just this will do:

```
<div class="btngrey">
    <span class="gfx"></span>
    <a href="#">All friends</a>
</div>
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KHkcx/).

Comment: It works! One problem though, I have an input field, and when clicking on it, the div doesn't slide up?

Comment: @Johan - I'm not following, where is the `<input>` field at? (and does *id* have a `return false` or `stopPropagation()` along the way?)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the HTML code?
It could be that you are hiding more elements than you want to. Or why do you have so many selectors: '.sortFriends .btngrey .gfx'

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you're attaching the click handler on body inside another click event and in body click event you're attaching another event. That will happen on each and every click. Are you sure you want to do that? try to attach the events in $(window).load.

Answer (score 0):

Removes the function from the **toggleSelectGroupList** function and puts in the **$(document).ready(function ()** ...

```
$('body').click(function(){  
    $('#groupListSortby').click(function(e) {    e.stopPropagation();   })
    $('#groupListSortby').hide(); 
    $('.sortFriends .btngrey .gfx').toggleClass('isActive');
    $('.sortFriends .btngrey a').toggleClass('isActive');
});
```